# PyQt5 still missing after brew install and updating python path

Tags: python, pyqt, homebrew, pyqt5

After successfully running `brew install pyqt` and updating my python path like so:

`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

But still I keep getting `ImportError: No module named PyQt5`. 
Even worse, when I use Homebrew-installed python3 to run my program, I still get errors like `ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type`

Comment: Using pip to install python libraries is more recommended

Comment: I think Homebrew will only install PyQt for the Python that comes with Homebrew, not for your regular (OS-X preinstalled) Python. Furthermore, you added the site-packages of 2.7 to your PYTHONPATH, but use Python 3. Try adding the site-packges of your Python 3.x to the PYTHONPATH.